# LLVM pass creation related

Tags: llvm

I want to create a pass that will insert a function (that is in some c file) after every load instruction.I know how to insert a function with no arguments.But a function that also have argument. I am not able to insert that.How should i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CallInst::Create` static method. It takes an `ArrayRef` of arguments. By grepping for this method call in the source of LLVM & Clang you can find many examples for using it.

Comment: Actually i am trying to pass the "loaded value" for this i need to pass the memory address..pass an integer is easy and i found many examples for that..but how to access this loaded value address and pass this and then accessing it..i am not clear over this